# How can I get FormControl value in child component?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

**I've found another way to solve my task. The question is no longer relevant.**

I have a component for my form with some form group I pass in it. I want get form control value inside a component, but it always returns empty string. Form in html template works perfect.

There is my component.ts code:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
    selector: 'obit-careers',
    templateUrl: 'careers.component.html'
})
export class CareersComponent implements OnInit{

    @Input() group: FormGroup;

    public blur: boolean[] = [];
    public year: number;

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('Object - ', this.group.controls.retirementYear);
        console.log('Value - ', this.group.controls.retirementYear.value);
    }
}
```

I can see object with all properties but I cant't get a value.

Screenshot:
[image: screen]

HTML Template.

```
<div [formGroup]="group">

<ion-row no-padding>
    <ion-col col-12 no-padding>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>
                {{ 'career.title' | translate }}
            </ion-label>
            <ion-input (ionBlur)="blur['career_title'] = true" clearInput type="text"
                       formControlName="title" minlength="2" maxlength="100">
            </ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <div *ngIf="blur['career_title'] && (
                                !group.controls.title.valid &&
                                !group.controls.title.pristine)">
            <label class="error-message">{{ 'error.invalid_text_field' | translate }}</label>
        </div>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>

<ion-row no-padding>
    <ion-col col-12 no-padding>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>
                {{ 'career.industry' | translate }}
            </ion-label>
            <ion-input (ionBlur)="blur['career_industry'] = true" clearInput type="text"
                       formControlName="industry" minlength="2" maxlength="100">
            </ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <div *ngIf="blur['career_industry'] && (
                                !group.controls.industry.valid &&
                                !group.controls.industry.pristine)">
            <label class="error-message">{{ 'error.invalid_text_field' | translate }}</label>
        </div>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>

<ion-row no-padding>
    <ion-col col-12 no-padding>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>
                {{ 'career.company' | translate }}
            </ion-label>
            <ion-input (ionBlur)="blur['career_company'] = true" clearInput type="text"
                       formControlName="company" minlength="2" maxlength="100">
            </ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <div *ngIf="blur['career_company'] && (
                                !group.controls.company.valid &&
                                !group.controls.company.pristine)">
            <label class="error-message">{{ 'error.invalid_text_field' | translate }}</label>
        </div>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>

<ion-row>
    <ion-col col-12 no-padding>
        <ion-item no-padding no-margin>
            <ion-label floating>
                {{ 'career.retirementYear' | translate }}
            </ion-label>
            <ion-datetime (ionBlur)="blur['retirementYear'] = true" displayFormat="YYYY"
                          pickerFormat="YYYY" formControlName="retirementYear"
                          [cancelText]="'button_cancel' | translate"
                          [doneText]="'button_approve' | translate">
            </ion-datetime>
        </ion-item>
        <div *ngIf="blur['retirementYear'] && (
                            !group.controls.retirementYear.valid &&
                            !group.controls.retirementYear.pristine)">
            <label class="error-message">{{ 'error.invalid_year' | translate }}</label>
        </div>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: Can you try using `this.group.get('retirementYear').value`.

Comment: @Florian be easy, pal. Welcome to OS, Pavel. Let's see what we can do.

Comment: Pavel, can you try to use https://stackblitz.com to create a minimal demo for us to re-produce this issue, thank you.

Comment: Pavel, why don't you send the value instead of the formcontrol ? Can your retirementYear change in parent's component while your child component has been instanciated ?

Comment: @Gunner the same result

Answer (score 0):

you should display your  html template let's see what you did there to ascertain that is not where the mistake is coming from. check your `careers.component.html` very well. You can also check your string interpolation to make sure your binding it very well.

Comment: Added html-code. As I said form works perfectly, all bindings, formControlName etc.  But I need to access to the value on component creation

Comment: if that is the case then  check @Component to make sure it is connecting to your html template. change your templateUrl to this : ` templateUrl: './careers.component.html'`